# html form will not submit in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have two pages in WordPress with the exact same form and the same scripts used in the form.

On first page, the form submits (although it is a little slow):
http://www.lifeleap.org/homepage-test/

On the other page, the form will not submit. The button seems to be locked up for some reason:
http://lifeleap.org/theme-test/

Any ideas on what may be causing the issue and what I need to do to fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: could you describe which scripts you are using? how? may you paste some code?

Comment: We can't see your server-side code.

Comment: You have `jc/amember-signup1.js` through `jc/amember-signup4.js` not downloading.  Since that's a signup form, I'm guessing someone put a file in the wrong spot.

Comment: I got the "jc/amember-signup1.js" fixed, although the second form is still not submitting. I just put original js in the head instead of calling it. As far as scripts or code, what what help for me to post?

Comment: I took the html form from aMember, a membership script on the site. I got the form html here (in aMember ):
http://www.lifeleap.org/manage/signup

I included the html form in the two WordPress pages.  

WordPress doesn't like js, so I took the js calls in the original aMember form script and inserted them into the head of the form pages I created in WordPress, using the CSS Javascript Toolbox WP plugin. 

Again, the first form (in my first post here) works fine using this method. The second form does not and I can't figure out why or what I need to do to fix it. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Got is fixed. There is a strange thing with the membership script I am using (aMember). There are optional unrelated WordPress plugins, unrelated to the forms I mentioned, but if these plugins are installed, in WordPress, the forms I mentioned work. I discovered this my mistake. Hopefully this will help someone if they ever have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got is fixed. There is a strange thing with the membership script I am using (aMember). There are optional unrelated WordPress plugins, unrelated to the forms I mentioned, but if these plugins are installed, in WordPress, the forms I mentioned work. I discovered this my mistake. Hopefully this will help someone if they ever have this issue.